# Which quality Windows compatible DAW?

Tags: audio-recording

I have a small project studio and for my, mainly small scale singer songwriter acoustic, projects I use an Intel Mac coupled to an RME FireFace in the studio. I run Logic Studio on that machine.

I am creating another small set-up away from the main studio using a Carillon built, i5 64bit Windows7  PC. I have a Focusright Forte linked to that PC but at the moment no DAW.

I work in the folk music singer songwriter field and my requirements are just not big enough to warrant a full blown Pro-Tools set up. However I do want software quality and access pro plug ins.

Your views and thoughts would be appreciated...

Thanks

Lozz

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Pro-tools is the only thing that can use Pro-Tools plug-ins. Almost all DAWs (with exception to Reason) use VSTs.

Most of the availible DAWs are good, it really depends on your workflow, so I would take note of that and start there.

Generally, they don't like software request questions on stack exchange, because the answers will usually be quite subjective.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Pro Tools or Pro Tools plugins. There are several great windows DAWs, all of which support great plugins.

Note: In my experience, many (but not all) of the plugins bundled with DAWs are not nearly as good as paid, third-party plugins.

Try these DAWs (don't have enough rep to post more than 2 links so you'll have to search for the rest):

[Steinberg - Cubase](http://www.steinberg.net/en/products/cubase/start.html)

[Presonus - Studio One](http://studioone.presonus.com/)

[Cakewalk - Sonar](https://www.cakewalk.com/products/SONAR/)

[MOTU - Digital Performer](http://www.motu.com/products/software/dp)

[Cockos - Reaper](http://www.reaper.fm/)